cargobuild fails,both sbf and bpf doest work,no such command: +solana Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directiv mean toinvoke`cargo` through`rustup`
i tried using cargo-build-sbf after failing with bpf , howvere i get the same error
anirudh@kiaraki:~/hello_world$ cargo build-bpf
error: no such command: +solana
    Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
    Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?

anirudh@kiaraki:~/hello_world$ cargo build-sbf
error: no such command: +solana
    Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
    Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?

anirudh@kiaraki:~/hello_world$ solana-install update
Install is up to date. d0ed878 is the latest commit for stable
anirudh@kiaraki:~/hello_world$
please help all the installation steps were strictly followed from
https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/setup-local-development
and
https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/local-rust-hello-world
however failiures occured in latter one, i have tried youtube but not luck, please help
also it seems like i may have a version mismatch(im super new)
anirudh@kiaraki:~/hello_world$  cargo-build-sbf --version  solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.17.25 platform-tools v1.37 rustc 1.68.0 anirudh@kiaraki:~/hello_world$ rustc -vV rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21) (built from a source tarball) binary: rustc commit-hash: 82e1608dfa6e0b5569232559e3d385fea5a93112 commit-date: 2023-12-21 host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu release: 1.75.0 LLVM version: 17.0.6 anirudh@kiaraki:~/hello_world$ ls
thank you

i tried fixing the version mismatch by chaning both of it to what others found compatible, maybe i need a longer tutorial but it didt work for me :(
